# How to lock a set of records without fetching them to the client

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc

Suppose we have a table similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  department_id INT NOT NULL,
  first_name NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
)
```

There may be multiple concurrent transactions operating on records of this table. If they operate the same `department_id`, they should be serializable/synchronized (i.e. wait for each other to commit or rollback):

```
-- 1-st statement
BEGIN TRANSACTION
-- 2-nd
SELECT * FROM employee WITH (ROWLOCK, XLOCK, HOLDLOCK) WHERE department_id = :department_id
-- 3-nd
... main logic ... 
-- 4-th
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

What I'd like to achieve is to avoid fetching all these records to the client (a Java application in my case) in the second statement, but instead just lock them in the database for this transaction, e.g. via calling some built-in stored procedure (and dynamic SQL in my example):

```
-- 1-st statement
BEGIN TRANSACTION
-- 2-nd, something like that
CALL sp_lock 'employee' 'ROWLOCK, XLOCK, HOLDLOCK' 'department_id = :department_id'
-- 3-nd
... main logic ... 
-- 4-th
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Is it possible in MS SQL Server (and also Java/JDBC in my case)?

Comment: You are looking for [sp_getapplock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: sounds like an idea...

Comment: Do you need to also lock against any *new* records being inserted with the same `department_id`? And I'd be interested to know *why* you want this, what does this offer over standard locking?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UPDLOCK` hint in a `SELECT` statement, and that will cause the lock to be held until the end of the transaction

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DECLARE @dummy int = (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM employee WITH (UPDLOCK)
  WHERE department_id = @department_id);

... main logic ... 

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

The `HOLDLOCK` hint will also take out a range lock against any *new* records being inserted with the same `department_id`, at the cost of possibly locking more than necessary (it locks up until the next existing key).

If you have other indexes then you need to force a clustered index to make this work properly, you can add the hint `INDEX (0)` or `INDEX (1)`

Comment: According to your example, aggregating functions lock all records matching their `where` clauses, e.g. `SELECT count(*) FROM employee WITH (ROWLOCK, XLOCK, HOLDLOCK) WHERE department_id = 123` does the same thing as `SELECT * FROM employee WITH (ROWLOCK, XLOCK, HOLDLOCK) WHERE department_id = 123` but returns just 1 record and 1 column to the client. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes although it depends if you have other indexes. Note that I don't return anything to client though because I'm storing it in a variable, but `XLOCK` in a `SELECT` is a misnomer and will not take an X lock, and either way you *need* `UPDLOCK` otherwise it doesn't work